# If $f(x)=\tilde{f}(\|x\|)$ and $f$ is continuous, is $\tilde{f}$ continuous?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am intrigued by this idea that has come to my mind. Let $f:A\subset\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$  be a continous funct, either in a point $x_0\in A$ or in all of its domain $A$, whose values only depend upon the absolute value $\|x\|$ of its argument $x$, and let $\tilde{f}$ be defined by $$\tilde{f}(\|x\|)=f(x).$$

Is $\tilde{f}$ continuous, in general? Although, intuitively, I would not exclude that $\tilde{f}$ must be continuous, I have not been able to prove it and am beginning to suspect that the implication does not hold in general. In fact, if $f$ is continuous in $x_0$, then $$\forall\varepsilon>0\quad\exists\delta>0:\forall x\in A\quad(\|x-x_0\|<\delta\Rightarrow \|f(x)-f(x_0)\|<\varepsilon)$$but the continuity of $\tilde{f}$ would be expressed by$$\forall\varepsilon>0\quad\exists\delta>0:\forall x\in A\quad(|\|x\|-\|x_0\||<\delta\Rightarrow \|f(x)-f(x_0)\|<\varepsilon)$$and we have that if $\|x-x_0\|<\delta$ then $|\|x\|-\|x_0\||<\delta$ but not the converse implication.

In the particular case that $A=\mathbb{R}^n$ [Uncountable's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1210347/if-fx-tildef-x-and-f-is-continuous-is-tildef-continuous#comment2462333_1210347) proves that $\tilde{f}\in C([0,\infty))$, but I am not sure about what happens in the more general case where $A\subsetneq\mathbb{R}^n$.

Does anybody reading this question know more about it?

Comment: Yes it is a standard result. The composition of two continuous functions is a continuous function.

Comment: @CTNT this is not what is asked.

Comment: So $\tilde f$ is defined on $[0,\infty)$? You can view it as the restriction of $f$ to the nonnegative $x_1$-axis, right?

Comment: @SantiagoCanez this might not be in $A$.

Comment: @quid, fair enough.

Comment: Possibly helpful: $$\tilde{f}:[0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}^n,\;\tilde{f}(x)=f(x,0,\cdots,0)$$

Comment: @Uncountable Interesting! That proves that $\tilde{f}$ is continuous (at least) **if** $A=\mathbb{R}^n$. I thank all the commenters!

Answer (score 3):

In general, this is certainly false. Take $A = (-1,0] \cup [1,2] \subset \Bbb R$, and define $f(a) = a$. Then $\tilde f(x)$ is defined on $[0,2]$, but $\tilde f(x)=x$ to the right of $x=1$ and $\tilde f(x)=-x$ to the left of $x=1$.

If $A$ is path-connected, then the idea in Santiago Canez/Uncountable's comments show that $\tilde f$ is indeed continuous.

Comment: Is path-connected necessary? I think "connected" might suffice, though I'm not sure.

Comment: Thank you very much!!! I see that if $A=\mathbb{R}^n$ then Santiago's comment shows that $\tilde{f}$ is continuous because $x=(x_1,...,x_n)\mapsto f(x_1,0,...,0)$ is, as it's the composition of $f$ with the continuous projection $x\mapsto x_1$, but I'm not able to prove to myself how it can be generalized to any path-connected $A$... Thank you again for any further explanation!

Comment: It's indeed interesting to ponder whether connected suffices—and also whether connected is necessary.

Comment: Oh, yes! If you have time to write a proof, at least for the path-connected case, I would be immensely grateful to you, as I already are for this answer!